# Set a variable to the < ("less than") operator as a function in Swift?

Tags: swift

There's a neat guide [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/80818/operator-overloading-in-swift-tutorial) about overloading operators in Swift, but it doesn't say anything about treating operators as functions that I can pass around as variables like any other function. I want to do something like `var comparator = (<)` to set a variable to the `<` function, but every syntax I've tried hasn't worked, and the Swift Programming Guide doesn't mention anything relevant. I know how to achieve a similar effect with a lambda expression, but that's messy. How can I set a variable to the `<` function?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you give `comparator` an explicit type, then it will work.

```
var comparator: (Int, Int) -> Bool = (<)
```

or

```
var comparator: (Double, Double) -> Bool = (<)
```

Less than `<` isn't a single function, but a whole collection of them for different types.  By identifying the type you are interested in comparing, you allow the compiler to select the correct less than function.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I was thinking too much of the weak-typed Python language.

Comment: But how to use the comparator then? `if 5 comperator 34 {}` fails.

Comment: @Daniel, you use it like this: `if comparator(5, 34) { }`.  When assigned to the variable, it is a closure/function and so must be called like one.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Thank you!